# Is the correct way to access ref in react?

Tags: reactjs, ref

Without using binding of this.say to this on button the example does not work. However I am not sure if it is right or has any side effects.

```js
class Speak extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input ref={(c) => this._input = c} defaultValue="Hello World!"/>
                <button onClick={this.say.bind(this) }>Say</button>
            </div>
        );
    }

    say() {
        if (this._input !== null) {
            alert(this._input.value);
        }
    }
};

ReactDOM.render(<Speak />, document.getElementById('App'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="App" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is required when using ES6 classes:  [See: Autobinding](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#autobinding)

Only difference is example above binds the method in constructor

Answer (score 0):

you can utilize array functions and forget about adding `.bind(this)`
check out working [pen](http://codepen.io/dagman/pen/vXRGkZ)

```
class Speak extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type='text' ref='greeting'/>
                <button onClick={this.say}>Say</button>
            </div>
        );
    }

    say = () => {
        const { value } = this.refs.greeting;
        alert(value);
        return value;
    };
};

ReactDOM.render(<Speak />, document.getElementById('App'));
```